# How strstr return is not a constant

Tags: c++, c, string

The standard function `strstr` is used to find the location of a sub-string in a string. Both the arguments of the function are of `const char *` type, but the return type is `char *`.

I would like to know how a standard function is implemented violating the const-correctness.

Comment: You are including cstring, and not string.h?  Otherwise, you're using C versions - god knows what they do.  The C++ `std::strstr` versions only returns `char*` if the first parameter is also a non-`const` `char*`.  See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr).  (Sorry - just noticed the C tag too... which language are you actually using?)

Comment: @TonyD The C version is `char * strstr ( const char *, const char * ); `

Comment: Note that in C++, there are [two overloads of strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) one with const char* parameter and one with normal char*, and the return values follow.

Comment: Please do not use C and C++ tags for the same question when the question is not about differences, similarities, making code that works in both languages or using functions from one language in the other language.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C allows pointing to memory with const or non-const pointers, regardless if the object was defined with the const qualifier or not.

> 6.5 Expressions
>
> 7. An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>      the following types:
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,

The prototype of strstr in C is:

```
char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

The returned pointer, if valid, points to string s1. This can be achieved with a cast:

```
const char safe = 's' ;
char* careful = ( char* )&safe ;
```

The problem is modifying that memory.

> 6.7.3 Type qualifiers
>
> 6. If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
>      of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, *the behavior is undefined.*

Since you created the string, you should know whether you can modify it or not, therefore you can accept the return value with a pointer to const, to avoid any problems:

```
const char* find = strstr( ... ) ;
```

Answer (score 29):

All the `const char *` is telling you is that `strstr` is not going to modify the string you pass into it.

Whether you modify the returned string or not is up to you as it is your string!

In C++ this has been changed by overloading the method and having two versions, the `const` input version has a `const` output.

In C it doesn't have quite that level of safety built in for you and assumes you know yourself whether you should be modifying the returned string.

Comment: What C doesn't have is actually function overloading. If the function were first introduced in C++, it might come in two flavors, const and non-const. But the function was first introduced in C. Moreover, it was introduced in K&R times, when there was no `const` keyword.

Answer (score 13):

According to ISO C++ 21.8(7) `strstr` returns a `const char*` or a `char*` depending on if it gets a `const char*` or a `char*`.

> ```
> const char* strstr(const char* s1, const char* s2);
>
> char* strstr( char* s1, const char* s2);
> ```

Comment: That's true for C++, but in C99 standard `strstr` returns `char*`.

Comment: I saw the C++ tag first so I used the C++ standard.  You are correct about the C standard.

Answer (score 5):

It's done by specifying the signature, and leaving the implementation up to the compiler builders.

Note that returning a `char*` which points to a `const char[]` string is just dangerous, but not yet a violation of any rule. However, any attempt to write to that memory is still Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 5):

The `strstr` function dates back to an era before there was such a thing as a `const` pointer.  In cases were it would be legal for code to write to memory identified by the first pointer passed to `strstr`, it would be legal for code to write to memory identified by the returned pointer, and in cases where the returned value would only be used in ways that were legal with a pointer to read-only memory (e.g. a string literal), one could legally pass such a pointer to `strstr`.

If a functionality similar to `strstr` were being defined today, it might be implemented using two methods--one of which could accept any pointer and return a pointer which could not be written by the recipient, and one of which would only accept writable pointers but would return a pointer that the recipient could use as it saw fit.  Because some code which used `strstr` would need to pass read-only pointers, however, and because some code which used `strstr` needed to be able to write to the pointers that it would yield when given writable pointers, it was necessary to have one set of pointer qualifications work both ways.  The consequence is a set of pointer qualifications which are not really "safe" [since it may return a writable pointer to a read-only area of memory] and which will let code compile in some cases where it really "shouldn't", but which will allow code written before the days of `const` pointers to continue working as intended.

Answer (score 2):

C++ [provides two versions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr) one that takes const arguments and ones that takes non-const.

```
const char* strstr( const char* str, const char* target );      
char* strstr(       char* str, const char* target );
```

Since in C we can not overload, we are left with two unpleasant choices:

- Either we take the arguments as non-const but if our sources are indeed const then we need to perform an unpleasant cast to non-const.
- The second option is the one we have which is that we take the arguments as const but we return a non-const. We could return a const char* but then we could never modify the result.

Answer (score 1):

The return value is not the variable that you have passed to the function as parameter. This function returns a pointer to the first occurrence in haystack of any of the entire sequence of characters specified in needle, or a null pointer if the sequence is not present in haystack.

Comment: It's still related to it (being part of the same array declaration or memory allocation), and therefore almost certainly has the same "proper const-ness" as haystack, if the function is being used correctly.